# Как сделать Итого в MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Нужно выбрать названия специальностей и количество студентов по каждой, а также всего , вот так:

```
    специальность 1              111
    специальность 2              222
    ...
    всего                        999
```

Вот что я сделал:

```
select 
specialty.name as specialty_name,
    count(id_grupa) as student_count
from grupa
left join specialty on
 specialty.id=grupa.id_specialty
left join student on
 student.id_grupa=grupa.id
group by specialty_name
order by student_count;
```

Не знаю как теперь вывести Всего:

Comment: подзапрос с юнион, либо group by rollup

Comment: то есть фактически добавиьт вам надо просто `group by ... with rollup`. если версия позволяет

Comment: А как тогда вместо NULL сделать надпись Всего?

Comment: как обычно `ifnull(name, 'Всего')` или `coalesce`

Comment: Где в запросе писать ifnull(name, 'Всего')?